# background thread blocks the UI thread for few seconds

Tags: asynchronous

I'm working on an application, and I'm using esri mechanisms for mapping services. I created a background thread, that loops through layers, executing spatial query on each layer to get back a list of features. but the background thread seems to block the UI thread for a couple of seconds and then start executing as required.

and the background thread periodically updates the UI thread.

I'm using background worker for this operation. thanks in advance

Comment: show your code, your platform and language...

Comment: Thanks Luaan for your response turns out I had to pause the background thread before it accesses the UI thread, to buy some time for the user to work on the UI thread. the UI thread was accessed frequently n short time intervals that causes the Interface to lock up.